# How to access IMM on IBM X3650 M3 from outside of LAN

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, remote-access, x-server

I just bought an IBM X3650 M3 and want to configure IMM on it. I connected the server's IMM port and can access the IMM module from any computer within my LAN (computers connected to the same router/modem). My problem is, how can I access the IMM module from outside of my router? I mean from the internet, provided I know my modem's public IP address.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out. I forwarded an unassigned port on my modem to my IMM IP address and now I can access it from anywhere using my modem's public IP along with the forwarded port.